# sql equivalent query filter django

Tags: sql, django, filter

What is the equivalent of this SQL statement in Django?

```
SELECT * FROM NAMES WHERE CONCAT (name,' ',last_name) LIKE '%Lennon%';
```

Comment: Please share your model.

Comment: SomeModel.objects.filter(full_name_icontains=...)

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Already shared my model, reload the page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since [django-3.2](/questions/tagged/django-3.2) one can work with [**`.alias(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#alias):

```
from django.db.models import Value
from django.db.models.functions import Concat

Names.objects.alias(
     total_name=Concat('name', Value(' '), 'last_name')
).filter(
    total_name__contains='Lennon'
)
```

prior to [django-3.2](/questions/tagged/django-3.2), we can work with [**`.annotate(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#alias):

```
from django.db.models import Value
from django.db.models.functions import Concat

Names.objects.annotate(
     total_name=Concat('name', Value(' '), 'last_name')
).filter(
    total_name__contains='Lennon'
)
```

---

> **Note**: normally a Django model is given a *singular* name, so `Name` instead of <s>`Names`</s>.

Comment: Thank you very much Willem, it worked for me, and I will take your recommendation.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you want to get all "names" where either first OR last name includes a particular string.  This can be achieved with Q objects:

```
Names.objects.filter(Q(name__icontains='Lennon') | Q(lastname__icontains='Lennon'))
```

See the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects).

Comment: Avi thanks for your answer, but this way i tried and dont work for me.